# TYPO3 - Encoding caching parameters in the filename

Tags: caching, proxy, typo3, cache-control

I've read that some proxies dont cache resources with "?" queries in their URL. [Reference](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageProxyCaching)

Is there a way to turn make the parameter a part of the filename?

(I guess that means turning style.css?v=123456 into style.123456.css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - there is such param called: **versionNumberInFilename**. You can set them in InstallTool->All Configuration or manually in typo3conf/localconf.php

Take care that there is such parameter for BE (backend) and separete for FE (frontend)

For backend you need to set it to "1". So finally in you typo3conf/localconf.php file there will be added line:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['versionNumberInFilename'] = '1'
```

For frontend you need to set it to "embed". So finally in you typo3conf/localconf.php file there will be added line:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['versionNumberInFilename'] = 'embed';
```

Then make sure the lines below are in your .htaccess so the files with numbers inside are properly resolved. In the latest versions of TYPO3 its by default active.

```
# Rule for versioned static files, configured through:
# - $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['versionNumberInFilename']
# - $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['versionNumberInFilename']
# IMPORTANT: This rule has to be the very first RewriteCond in order to work!
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ $1.$3 [L]
```